# Error while running react-native app please help me

Tags: android, react-native, gradle

WARNING: Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.
It will be removed soon. For more information see: http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html
WARNING: The specified Android SDK Build Tools version (23.0.1) is ignored, as it is below the minimum supported version (28.0.3) for Android Gradle Plugin 3.5.2.
Android SDK Build Tools 28.0.3 will be used.
To suppress this warning, remove "buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'" from your build.gradle file, as each version of the Android Gradle Plugin now has a default version of the build tools.

> Task :app:processDebugResources FAILED

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.9/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
234 actionable tasks: 14 executed, 220 up-to-date

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> Android resource linking failed
> C:\coding\App\storyqube-frontend\android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml:13:5-71:19: AAPT: error: resource mipmap/storyqube (aka com.storyqube:mipmap/storyqube) not found.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 18s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> Android resource linking failed
> C:\coding\App\storyqube-frontend\android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml:13:5-71:19: AAPT: error: resource mipmap/storyqube (aka com.storyqube:mipmap/storyqube) not found.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 18s

```
at makeError (C:\coding\App\storyqube-frontend\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)
at C:\coding\App\storyqube-frontend\node_modules\execa\index.js:278:16
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
at async runOnAllDevices (C:\coding\App\storyqube-frontend\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:94:5)      
at async Command.handleAction (C:\coding\App\storyqube-frontend\node_modules\react-native\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:186:9)
```

PS C:\coding\App\storyqube-frontend>

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check your build.gradle files in your android folder and search for compile and replace it it with `implementation`.

Change:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1"
    compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
    compile project(':react-native-sqlite-storage')
}
```

To:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1"
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
    implementation project(':react-native-sqlite-storage')
}
```

Comment: dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.2")
        classpath("com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3")

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    this is what i found in dependencies section in build.gradle there is no use of compile in it

Comment: There are several build.gradle files …
Check your build.gradle under yourProject/android/app/build.gradle

Comment: it already has "implementation " written on the code should I change it to compile

Comment: its not working i tried it

Comment: compile is outdated